# SQLite, check if TEXT field has any alphabetical chars in it

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete

Okay, so I have a huge list of entries, and in one of the columns (for simplicity let's call it ***num*** there's a number, something like `123456780000` (they are all the same length and format), but sometimes there are fields that look something like this

```
12345678E000 
or 
12345678H000
```

Now, I need to delete all the rows in which the ***num*** column is not entirely numeric. The type of ***num*** is *TEXT*, not *INTEGER*. So the above examples should be deleted, while `123456780000` should not.

I have tried two solutions, of which one works but is inelegant and messy, and the other one doesn't work at all.

The first thing I tried is

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE abs(num) == 0.0
```

Because according to the documentation, *abs(X)* returns exactly 0.0 if a *TEXT* value is given and is unconvertable to an real number. So I was thinking it should let all the "numbers-only" pass and delete the ones with a character in it. But it doesn't do a thing, it doesn't delete even a single row.

The next thing I tried is

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE num LIKE "%A%" OR "%B%" OR "%C%"
```

Which seems to work, but the database is large and I am not sure which characters can appear, and while I could just do `"%D%" OR "%E%" OR "%F%" OR ...` with the entire alphabet, this feels inelegant and messy. And I actually want to learn something about the SQLite language.

My question, finally, is: how do I solve this problem in a nice and simple way? Perhaps there's something I'm doing wrong with the *abs(X)* solution, or is there another way that I do not know of/thought of?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
According to a comment I tried `SELECT abs(num) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE num like '%A%'`
and it returned the following

```
12345678.0
```

That's strange. It seems it has split the number where the alphabetical appeared. The documentation claimed it would return 0.0 if it couldn't convert it to a number. Hmm..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`GLOB`](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) in SQLite with a range to single them out:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE num GLOB '*[A-Za-z]*'
```

See it in use with this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4bc21/10

For example, for these records:

```
   num
----------
1234567890
0987654321
1000000000
1000A00000
1000B00000
1000c00000
```

`GLOB '*[A-Za-z]*'` will return these three:

```
   num
----------
1000A00000
1000B00000
1000c00000
```

You can then translate that to the appropriate `DELETE`:

```
DELETE 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE num GLOB '*[A-Za-z]*'
```

Comment: `WHERE num GLOB '*[A-z]*'` makes it even shorter.