# SQLite: Get only character string from text column

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

Table: `Test1`

```
Text_Column
------------
2021AB022
1A012998F
ZAY
212P09990
1232124
PMP
```

Expected result is:

```
Only_text
----------
ZAY
PMP
```

Try:

```
SELECT Text_Column AS Only_text
FROM Test1
WHERE Text_Column REGEXP '(A,Z)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite in fact supports `REGEXP`, then you were on the right track:

```
SELECT Text_Column AS Only_text
FROM Test1
WHERE Text_Column REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
```

But not all versions of SQLite would ship with `REGEXP` out of the box.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528759/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-a-number-in-sqlite) is another SO question which discusses other ways to detect a number.

Comment: Okay, Can you tell me what will be the wildcard for not equal to only characters? Just opposite of what you did.

Comment: Use `NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$` or maybe `REGEXP '[^A-Z]'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this solves your problem, but works for the given example:

```
SELECT * FROM Test1 WHERE
Text_Column GLOB '*[^0-9]*';
```

giving back only the columns not containig characters in the range 0-9.